# Windows Defender using 50% cpu. Can I ask it what it is spending its time on?

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, windows-defender

I am a Java developer and have a company Windows 10 PC where the Windows Defender Antivirus service typically uses 40-50% CPU and 10-20 MB/s disk according to task manager.   After being idle all night the service uses 8% cpu and has 10 MB/s disk traffic so any pending full scans should have completed.   This is extra annoying because the fans keep running.

I have local administrator rights, but most security settings are locked down.

Is there a way to ask Defender what it is spending its time on, so I can ask the powers that be to reconsider any unfortunate settings or simply fix anything that defender might be hiccupping on?

Comment: Run: `wpr.exe -start -GeneralProfile` when you have the issue, and leave it for say 30 seconds to 1 minute then run `wpr.exe -stop GeneralProfileWD.etl`.  Once you have the ETL trace, from the Windows Store get Windows Performance Analyzer (WPR), you can get it from the ADK as well but the Store is pretty convenient.  You should be able to use just the CPU sampled view to identify roughly what's going on.  Maybe also use the Disk view to look at the files.  If you need a hand, maybe share the file.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible actions:

- Verify that only one instance of `MsMpEng.exe` is executing and verify its folder.
  On my Windows 10 computer this is
  `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\4.18.1907.4-0`.
  A bogus process means virus infection.
- Use
  [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
  run as Admin to examine the files that the process is opening.
  This is done by setting menus *View > Show Lower Pane* and also
  *View > Lower Pane View > Handles*, then click column "Type" to sort by it.
  Surprisingly, the files have the type of "File".
- Some reports say that adding the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender`
  to the exclusion list of Windows Defender seems to calm it down.
  This is done in
  *Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security > Open Windows Security*,
  then *Virus & threat protection > Manage settings > Add or remove exclusions >
  Add an exclusion*.